# VBA code for finding the Max and Min values in a range looping on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, max, min

Help anyone!!

I've been trying lots and lots of code but nothing seems to work. What VBA code can I use?

Data details: On every column N of my 50 sheets, I have data in percentage format. I need to find the min and max of those numbers in my 50 sheets and return the value to my top page.

I am **very new** to VBA and I cannot seem to figure it out. Any advice is much appreciated!!

Comment: `Application.Min` and `Application.Max`.

Comment: How were you able to loop it on all the sheets? I used that but whenever I let it loop across sheets it wouldn't work

Comment: `For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Do you want the min/max for each sheet, or considering all the sheets together?

Comment: Hi again BigBen! I am looking for the min/max considering all the data sheets together. I am using this code but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work.                               Dim ws As Worksheet

'For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'     Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("N:N"))
'Next ws

Comment: Is there any other way to get the min/max function?

Comment: You need to keep track of the overall max/min as you loop, comparing it to the max/min of each sheet and taking the higher/lower of the two options.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a formula?
=MAX(Sheet1!N:N,Sheet2!N:N,,Sheet3!N:N) etc...

Comment: Well you would want a 3-d formula, right? `=MAX(Sheet1:Sheet50!N:N)`.

Comment: I need a VBA script for this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a huge data set with multiple columns where the total number of columns and their locations are dynamic and never constant?

Can we assume you have column headers? If so, assuming your headers are in Row 1 starting with Col A and your data starts in A2, you could do this at the top of each sheet to get the max value of your percent column:

```
=MAX(INDEX($A$2:$Z$1000, , MATCH("YOUR HEADER NAME HERE WHERE %s ARE", $A$1:$Z$1,0)))
```

If you need to do this on all sheets and put it at the top of just one page you could vba script a loop through all the sheets:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
         Dim Current As Worksheet

         ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
         For Each Current In Worksheets

            ' Insert your code here.
            ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
            MsgBox Current.Name
         Next

      End Sub
```